# Enable a LinkButton nested inside a disabled GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a Gridview that has Enabled="False" (it contains many controls and in this circumstance i need them all to be disabled, easiest way is to set Enabled="False" on the Gridview).

The issue is I want to enable one LinkButton on each row within the disabled Gridview. I've tried finding the LinkButton on RowDataBound and enabling it there but it's still disabled. Can this be done? Can you have an enabled Button within a disabled GridView?

Simplified example of the code (real one is thousands of lines long)

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" enabled="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="button-to-be-enabled" text="press me"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Try using jQuery to enable something like $(".linkButtonClass").removeAttr("disabled"); where "linkButtonClass" is the CssClass of all the Link Buttons

Comment: Hi Praveen, but is that how setting a gridview enabled=false works? Looking at the source in the browser the button itself doesn't appear to be disabled.

Comment: @Praveen that does not work. The `href` part is also missing so just enabling the button won't work.

Comment: You are putting a box (linkbutton) into another box (gridview). So, if you close the outer box, you can not reach and open the inner one. It seams like that you do not want to run your browser but surf on the internet.

Comment: Where are you setting the URL for Link Button?

Comment: @Praveen the link button is handled in the code-behind.

Comment: @MuratSEKERMCT I had a feeling that was the case but was hoping there was a way around it. If there is no easy way to disable everything in a GridView and then re-enable something, that means I have to disable hundreds of controls manually for that GridView, which is not ideal.

Comment: No that's not possible